# Why this Python code can't print out global variable outside of it's function

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I understand that `b` is local variable.
But `c` is global variable. Why can't I print it out outside of it's function?

```
a = 5

def func():
    b = 8
    global c
    c = 9

print(a)
# print(b)
print(c)        # line 10
```

Output

```
c:\Users\test>py script.py
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(c)
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

c:\Users\test>
```

Comment: You never called the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you define `func()`, that is not invoked/called anywhere in the code. So, the global variable `c` won't be defined in the runtime.

```
print(a)
# print(b)
func() # without this, the variable won't be defined in the runtime.
print(c)
```

The program can't define a variable before it reaches it and to reach c you have to call func.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `func` firts, otherwise `global c`  will never defined